# is JQ Transform modifying numbers? How can I get past it?

Tags: jq, jqtransform

Why this ("Filter" in jqplay.org):
{"key":633447818234478180}

returns this ("Result" in jqplay.org):
{"key": 633447818234478200}

Original JSON doesn't matter.

Why is it changing 180 into 200? How can I overcome this? Is this a bug? A number too big?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is because jq can only represent legal JSON data and the number you've given is outside the range that can be represented without loss of precision.  See also

- [What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin#307200)

If you need to work with larger numbers as strings in jq you may want to try this library:

- [jq-bigint](https://github.com/joelpurra/jq-bigint)
  A big integer library for working with possibly-signed arbitrarily long decimal strings. Written by Peter Koppstein (@pkoppstein) and released under the MIT license.